# adding timer to mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` for playing the sound and video. I am streaming the song from the url. It is working fine.But the problem is, `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is not showing the time progress for the song I playing. That bar is disabled. How to make the time progress bar active? I have following  code to play the song.

```
    mediaPlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:songUrl];
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPlayerController animated:YES];
    [[mediaPlayerController moviePlayer] play];
```

[image]

Comment: i think bar is not disabled. it takes time to load song (buffering the data)

Comment: @Prince:No it is not showing the timer throughout the song.If i have duration of the song then can i put that into the slider?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the current progress time on your own custom way, you can show it by using the `currentPlaybackTime` property in the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol gives you that info.

Answer (score 0):

U use AVPlayer for playing live streaming. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431517/http-live-streaming-with-avplayer-in-ios-4-0) link.

Also refer [StitchedStreamPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html) link sample code by apple.

---

Set controlStyle for mediaPlayerController:

```
  [mediaPlayerController moviePlayer].controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
```

Comment: No,its not working i have added the screen shot of my media player . you will get some idea.